# Next.js access Page props inside the getServerSideProps method

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm passing some properties to the  on the `_app` page.

```
<PageWrapper>
  <Component someProps={someProps} />
  <GlobalCSS />
 </PageWrapper>
```

Is it possible to access these props in the getServerSideProps method on each Page?

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async context => {
  const data = await fetchData(someProps); // ??
  
  return { props: { data } };
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Lets say you have a page `demo` with

```
// ...
export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const demo = await fetch('/api/demo');

  return {
    props: {
      demo,
    }
  };
};
```

and somewhere in your other child component you can access it

```
export const MyComponent = () => {
  const { components } = useRouter();

  console.log(components['demo'].props.pageProps);
};
```

> **Attention!** This is undocumented and hacky way.

Answer (score -5):

You can check this [Next JS](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps) document fetching data and use. I hope so this is usefull for you !

Comment: I don't need to fetch the data, I need to access the props I've provided in the _app page.